# ReactJS - Function to be implemented in a lot of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this component i'm using the `noMoreLonelyWords()` utilitarian function which is working good. It's objective is to render the paragraph without single word in the last line, like this example:

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Column1 from './Column1'
import Column2 from './Column2'
import FooterMobile from './FooterMobile'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)     
    this.noMoreLonelyWords = this.noMoreLonelyWords.bind(this)
  }


  noMoreLonelyWords = (selector, numWords) => {      
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) { 
      var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");      
      var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("&nbsp;");     
      var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
      elems[i].innerHTML = textMinusLastWords + " " + lastWords;
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(){   
  this.noMoreLonelyWords("p", 2)
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <div className="wrapper-all">
          <Column1 />
          <Column2 />
          <FooterMobile />
        </div>    
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

My question is that this function will be used by multiple child components that contains paragraph. That's why I wanted to know the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `utilities.js` file and put

```
  export const noMoreLonelyWords = (selector, numWords) => {      
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) { 
      var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");      
      var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("&nbsp;");     
      var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
      elems[i].innerHTML = textMinusLastWords + " " + lastWords;
    }
  }
```

Then in your components import it using

```
import {noMoreLonelyWords} from 'path/to/utilities';
```

and use it directly, example:

```
componentDidUpdate(){   
  noMoreLonelyWords("p", 2)
}
```